# How to dynamically change resource class in Django Import-Export admin based on user group?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export, django-admin-tools

I am using Django Import-Export library to manage export functionalities in my Django admin interface. I have a requirement where I need to dynamically change the resource class based on the user's group membership.

Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .resources import RawFileDMDResource, RawFileResource
    
    class RawFileAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = RawFileResource
        [...]
        def get_resource_class(self, request=None):
            resource_class = self.resource_class
            if request is None:
                user = get_user()
            else:
                user = request.user
    
            if user.groups.filter(name='DMD ext_users').exists():
                resource_class = RawFileDMDResource
            return resource_class
```

However, the get_resource_class method expects a request argument. It seems that the Import-Export library doesn't provide the request object in the context of this method.

Is there a way to access the current user's information or request object within the get_resource_class method without explicitly passing the request object?

Comment: It looks like you're on a pre v3 version of django-import-export.  Can you upgrade to v3 or v4 (even better)?

Comment: Hi! i'm using django-import-export==3.2.0. Max version released is: 3.3.7 https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html Still not working. It seems the function get_resource_class is not getting any request and that's why I can't get the user. ¿is there any other way to do it? maybe inside teh resource?

Comment: Just to clarify the final objective. The users in group  user.groups.filter(name='DMD ext_users') has a different resource as the fields to export (inside class Meta:) Are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not easy to do this with the current codebase.

One option would be to override the entire `export_action()` method so that you can add code to make selections based on the `request` instance.

For example, you could pass the request into [`get_export_resource_classes()`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/493ff3c65131814ecd5ef5d12ee547c60bc253fd/import_export/admin.py#L824).

You can then override `get_export_resource_classes()` and add your selection logic there.

It would be a lot easier to return a Resource class based on request properties if this were passed into the method.  I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1778) for this to be implemented.  Feel free to submit a PR if you use this approach.

Comment: It works using get_export_resource_classes(). Thanks.